# No internet in WINE 1.6.2 under Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, software-installation, wine, internet, 15.10

I am trying to install [Metatrader](http://www.metatrader4.com/en) under Wine. The program setup continually requests proxy settings. My broker tells me this shouldn't happen, and is a problem on my end. Here is what I have tried to attempt to solve this error:

- I have gone into Network settings and proxy is set to none.
- I have looked in Wine Regedit and `proxy_enable` is set to 0.
- I have checked the firewall settings on my modem.
- I have tried reinstalling wine.
- I have installed lib32nss-mdns
- I can log on to my modem in iexplore using the gateway ip but thats it
  I've set my DNS to 10.0.0.138 to reflect the gateway
  I've set up a 32 bit Wine prefix

How should I proceed in solving this?

Comment: I see they have in the instruction a command for installing 1.5 version. I hope you didn't install that version? Because it's really ancient, nowadays you'd rather use at least 1.7 or 1.8.

Comment: [Appdb says](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2893) it's enough to install `libgnutls28:i386` package. But I tried to test it, and for me that didn't work *(wine-1.9.2 btw)*. As it is worked before, guess they changed something which broke their executable in wine. [You can either report a bug to wine team](https://wiki.winehq.org/Bugs), or — which is better — report the bug to the brokers, because since they decided to support Ubuntu not with building a separate executable, but rather with Wine, then the burden of resolving Wine bugs is on their shoulders.

Comment: Tried installing libgnutls28:i386  but still no luck. I now have Metatrader installed in XP under Virtual Box. I'll tray again with Wine after the next update. Installed from the 15.10 Ubuntu repo. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=250393 - permissions mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a real newbie problem, a little embarrassing. I hadn't added the correct repo and was installing from an old repo. (Ubuntu 12.04 I think). Added the winehq repo and reinstalled. All working fine now. Was wondering why I was only getting 1.6.2.

Comment: I don't think it's a "newbie problem". I'm having the same issue, and if I'm running ubuntu 16.04 I expect "sudo apt-get install wine" to get a recent version of wine that will work on Ubuntu 16.04. If it gets an older/broken version, something is wrong in Ubuntu as a distribution.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install winhttp.dll, the following command would work:

```
winetricks winhttp
```

If any 404 error occurs when downloading W2KSP4_EN.EXE, try manually downloaded this file from the Wayback Machine [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160129053851/http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/6/A/E6A04295-D2A8-40D0-A0C5-241BFECD095E/W2KSP4_EN.EXE). 
and put it under $HOME/.cache/winetricks/win2ksp4/, Then rerun winetricks winhttp.

EDIT: Some people are having trouble with the Wayback Machine link. Another source is [this](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pc/security/ms-patches/win2000/Service_Packs/usa/W2KSP4_EN.EXE) from the Free University of Berlin FTP Archives.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a similar issue in Ubuntu 20.04 with another application. It can't connect to the internet.

This forum on [winehq](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Failed_to_use_ICMP_.28network_ping.29.2C_this_requires_special_permissions) has some tips.

I've tried this (from @Serg comment), but didn't work for me:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+epi <wine_executable_path>
```

On my case, I noticed that running wine with `sudo` solved my problem. But, I know this is not recommended, because of security issues.

```
wine cmd
Microsoft Windows 5.2.3790

Z:\home\helesto>ping www.google.com

Pinging www.google.com [142.250.78.228] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
```

```
sudo wine cmd
Microsoft Windows 6.1.7601

Z:\home\helesto>ping www.google.com
Pinging www.google.com [142.250.78.228] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 142.250.78.228: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=115
```

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? Same problem here.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed Metatrader 4 on Lubuntu 16.04 with wine 1.9.16. Internet issue is solve by installing winbind:

```
sudo apt install winbind
```

It should help for any other version of Ubuntu.

Winbind is a component of the Samba suite of programs that solves the unified logon problem. Winbind uses a UNIX implementation of Microsoft RPC calls.

Comment: didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider seting raw network permissions.

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+epi <wine_executable_path>
```

To get wine executable path:

```
$ ls -la `which wine64-stable`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Apr 20  2020 /usr/bin/wine64-stable -> ../lib/wine/wine64
```

Use this path:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+epi /usr/lib/wine/wine64
```